# Parse issue expected identifier xcode

Tags: objective-c

Im getting an, Parse issue expected identifier  on the - (IBAction)Next: { and Im not sure how to fix it. Please help! ( Im also getting an Method definition for 'Next' not found if that matters)

```
@implementation MenuViewController

- (IBAction)Next: {
    MainViewController *second = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViesController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: It's the colon. Either get rid of it or add the needed parameter after it.

Answer (score 0):

In your xib/Story board click on the next button

go to show connection inspector

remove next: form it by clicking on x

[image]